# How to add "UISwipeGestureRecognizer" and "TapGestureRecognizer" in Same viewcontroller in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I need left swipe gesture for my viewcontroller and in the same viewcontroller i have one imageView if i click that imageView i need to use "UITapGestureRecognizer" and push to another viewcontroller to show that full image in another viewcontroller

**code:** here respondToSwipeGesture is working i am able to go back but **tap gesture for `profileImageView` is not working.** when i tap on image break point also not hitting. how to make it work. please guide me.

```
class CommentViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    
    profileImageView.addTapGestureRecognizer { [weak self] in
        self?.gotoStudentProfile()
    }
}

private func gotoStudentProfile() {
let vc = Helper.getVcObject(vcName: .StudentProfileViewController, storyboardName: .Profile) as! StudentProfileViewController
checkAndPushPop(vc, navigationController: navigationController)
 }

fileprivate typealias Action = (() -> Void)?

fileprivate var tapGestureRecognizerAction: Action? {
    set {
        if let newValue = newValue {
            // Computed properties get stored as associated objects
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectKeys.tapGestureRecognizer, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }
    get {
        let tapGestureRecognizerActionInstance = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObjectKeys.tapGestureRecognizer) as? Action
        return tapGestureRecognizerActionInstance
    }
}

 public func addTapGestureRecognizer(action: (() -> Void)?) {
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.tapGestureRecognizerAction = action
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
 }  

@objc fileprivate func handleTapGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let action = self.tapGestureRecognizerAction {
        action?()
    } else {
        print("no action")
    }
}
```

Comment: I rolled back the last edit. Please do not edit your question with the answer. It makes your whole question irrelevant if it doesn't have an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `UIImageView` has `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `false`. You have to set it to `true`.
Also, since you have not shared the implementation of the `addTapGestureRecognizer` method, make sure that it does not have any bugs.

Answer (score 1):

```
profileImageView.addTapGestureRecognizer
```

above this code set `isUserInteractionEnabled` enable for image

```
profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

**Updated**

```
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))

    profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    // function which is triggered when handleTap is called
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Hello World")
    }
```

Try this way and let me know